# Need to enable backup replication feature in AWS RDS through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, backup, amazon-rds, replication

Need to enable backup replication feature in AWS RDS - oracle through terraform. So do we have any attributes from terraform side for that particular feature?

Answer (score 1):

There is a resource you can use

`aws_db_instance_automated_backups_replication`

[Link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance_automated_backups_replication) to TF Docs.

Answer (score 0):

The only argument on the Terraform side is `aws_db_instance`'s [replicate_source_db](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#replicate_source_db)

> replicate_source_db - (Optional) Specifies that this resource is a Replicate database, and to use this value as the source database. This correlates to the identifier of another Amazon RDS Database to replicate (if replicating within a single region) or ARN of the Amazon RDS Database to replicate (if replicating cross-region). Note that if you are creating a cross-region replica of an encrypted database you will also need to specify a kms_key_id.

The `replicate_source_db` should have the ID or ARN of the source database.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "oracle" {
  # ... other arguments
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "oracle_replicant" {
  # ... other arguments

  replicate_source_db = aws_db_instance.oracle.id
}
```

Reference

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/oracle-read-replicas.html